# How to convert the int number into money format in X-path expression?

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I want to convert the number (ie.1000) directly into into the money format like(ie.1,000).how should i do that?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT there is format-number(), but in pure XPath you'll have to do it the hard way. Perhaps you should do the formatting in the host language that you call XPath from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number($wartosc, &quot;###,###,###,###,##0.00&quot;)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

If $number  is a string containing your integer number, then you can use:

```
replace(replace(
  if (string-length($number) mod 3 eq 2) then concat("0", $number) 
  else if (string-length($number) mod 3 eq 1) then concat("00", $number)
  else $number, 
  "([0-9]{3})", ",$1"), 
 "^[,0]+", "")
```